# React app pages are indexed but not visible in google search, Also not getting indexed on bing

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, spring-boot, server-side-rendering, bing

I have created a blog website using React as frontend and Java spring boot as backend + mongodb. Pages are indexed on google but not visible in search, also I tried submitting sitemaps and manually submitting url on bing but it shows guidelines not met.

[SS from bing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Kdk.png)

As before the API call complete data is not visible. ( I am fetching Heading, Meta and body from api call )

I am dynamically adding the new blog post and saving its html body in MongoDB and then fetching it using api call.

I have also tried searching for implementation of SSR in React already built application but not able to find something concrete.

Can someone please point me to the right direction.